# bottom navigation custom shape with shadow

Tags: android, shadow, bottomnavigationview

I'm using [BottomNavigationViewEx](https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx) with custom shape (picture and code below). I want to make shadow on top of the navigation. Tried adding LinearLayout with shadow drawable or elevation. But line is drawn strait, ignoring custom shape. How i can implement this with custom shape? Thanks!

[image: Current behavior]

Layout:

```
<com.example.CurvedBottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/main_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/menu_selector"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/menu_selector"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

Custom class:

```
class CurvedBottomNavigationView extends BottomNavigationViewEx {
    private Path mPath;
    private Paint mPaint;

    /** the CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS represent the radius of the fab button */
    private final int CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS = 128 / 2;
    // the coordinates of the first curve
    private Point mFirstCurveStartPoint = new Point();
    private Point mFirstCurveEndPoint = new Point();
    private Point mFirstCurveControlPoint1 = new Point();
    private Point mFirstCurveControlPoint2 = new Point();

    //the coordinates of the second curve
    @SuppressWarnings("FieldCanBeLocal")
    private Point mSecondCurveStartPoint = new Point();
    private Point mSecondCurveEndPoint = new Point();
    private Point mSecondCurveControlPoint1 = new Point();
    private Point mSecondCurveControlPoint2 = new Point();
    private int mNavigationBarWidth;
    private int mNavigationBarHeight;

    public CurvedBottomNavigationView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CurvedBottomNavigationView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CurvedBottomNavigationView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mPath = new Path();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        // get width and height of navigation bar
        // Navigation bar bounds (width & height)
        mNavigationBarWidth = getWidth();
        mNavigationBarHeight = getHeight();
        // the coordinates (x,y) of the start point before curve
        mFirstCurveStartPoint.set((mNavigationBarWidth / 2) - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 3), 0);
        // the coordinates (x,y) of the end point after curve
        mFirstCurveEndPoint.set(mNavigationBarWidth / 2, CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 4));
        // same thing for the second curve
        mSecondCurveStartPoint = mFirstCurveEndPoint;
        mSecondCurveEndPoint.set((mNavigationBarWidth / 2) + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 3), 0);

        // the coordinates (x,y)  of the 1st control point on a cubic curve
        mFirstCurveControlPoint1.set(mFirstCurveStartPoint.x + CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 4), mFirstCurveStartPoint.y);
        // the coordinates (x,y)  of the 2nd control point on a cubic curve
        mFirstCurveControlPoint2.set(mFirstCurveEndPoint.x - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) + CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS, mFirstCurveEndPoint.y);

        mSecondCurveControlPoint1.set(mSecondCurveStartPoint.x + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) - CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS, mSecondCurveStartPoint.y);
        mSecondCurveControlPoint2.set(mSecondCurveEndPoint.x - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 4)), mSecondCurveEndPoint.y);

        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(0, 0);
        mPath.lineTo(mFirstCurveStartPoint.x, mFirstCurveStartPoint.y);

        mPath.cubicTo(mFirstCurveControlPoint1.x, mFirstCurveControlPoint1.y,
                mFirstCurveControlPoint2.x, mFirstCurveControlPoint2.y,
                mFirstCurveEndPoint.x, mFirstCurveEndPoint.y);

        mPath.cubicTo(mSecondCurveControlPoint1.x, mSecondCurveControlPoint1.y,
                mSecondCurveControlPoint2.x, mSecondCurveControlPoint2.y,
                mSecondCurveEndPoint.x, mSecondCurveEndPoint.y);

        mPath.lineTo(mNavigationBarWidth, 0);
        mPath.lineTo(mNavigationBarWidth, mNavigationBarHeight);
        mPath.lineTo(0, mNavigationBarHeight);
        mPath.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`MaterialShapeDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/shape/MaterialShapeDrawable) class can be used to create drawables with custom shapes that handles shadows and elevation. It gives much flexibility and also supports [animations](https://material.io/components/app-bars-bottom#behavior), for example bottom bar with cradle for fab (from [matherial designs](https://material.io/design/shape/about-shape.html)) is implemented with `MaterialShapeDrawable`:

[image: bottom bar with cradle]

It seems to me that it can be useful for you to draw the custom top side with shadow. Code example of material shape drawable can be found in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62199886/5116572) which solves the similar problem.